# How to write in and read from a data file in the same model with in the same .model in cplex?

Tags: program-entry-point, cplex

How to write in and read from a data file in the same model with main in the same .model in cplex?

Comment: @Alex Fleischer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you use https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplexcel/blob/main/zooexcelstrings.mod that reads and writes in excel through a dat file

```
string excelstrings[1..100][1..26]=...;

assert excelstrings[1][1]=="nbKids";
assert excelstrings[1][2]=="zizeBuses";
assert excelstrings[1][3]=="costBuses";

int nbKids=atoi(excelstrings[2][1]);


// a tuple is like a struct in C, a class in C++ or a record in Pascal
tuple bus
{
key int nbSeats;
float cost;
}

// This is a tuple set
{bus} buses={ <intValue(excelstrings[i][2]),floatValue(excelstrings[i][3])>|i in 2..100 :excelstrings[i][2]!=""};

// asserts help make sure data is fine
assert forall(b in buses) b.nbSeats>0;
assert forall(b in buses) b.cost>0;

// decision variable array
dvar int+ nbBus[buses];

// objective
minimize
 sum(b in buses) b.cost*nbBus[b];
 
// constraints
subject to
{
 sum(b in buses) b.nbSeats*nbBus[b]>=nbKids;
}

// output 
execute
{
 excelstrings[1][5]="result";
 for(var b in buses) excelstrings[Opl.ord(buses,b)+2][5]=nbBus[b];
```

}

if at the end of the .mod you add

```
main
{
  thisOplModel.generate();
  cplex.solve();
  thisOplModel.postProcess();
}
```

then it works fine and you have a model that reads and writes with a .mod and a main inside

Comment: thank you alex but this wasn't my question, Iam asking about how to write a variable array from .mod file to .data file then read the same variable to the same .mod file again to use it in another constrains. because this variable is exceuted after the constrains and i want to use it in another constrains in the same model. so my structure is that (constrains {} ... then after processing variable then write it in data file then read it to use it in next constrains.  is it valid to have two subject to in the same model.

Comment: You could either several model or  add incrémental constraints like https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooincremental.mod